# Line between two TextBlocks and fixing the position of elements

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface, email

I'm new to Visual Studio and WPF applications. I am trying to make XAML GUI for email and now I am stucked.

I created two TextBlocks which are displaying the content of email and now I want to make border between them, something like that:

Some text from message 1

---

Some text from message 2.

Actually I don't want to make full border around whole TextBlock, but just on bottom of the first one, or straight line between first and second (if that is even possible, if not, border all over around will be good too as solution).

Also I want to fix my problem with positions of elements (I have TextBlocks, TreeViews and ListViews). My workspace is Height="400" Width="625", and when I Start my GUI, and drag & resize window I mess up whole text and construction of my GUI.

I hope you are able to help me, if someone does not understand anything in my question, feel free to ask, I will try to explain it more specific.

In addition, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with WPF, I would highly recommend editing the XAML directly rather than using the designer. You **WILL** be alot more productive!

Anyway you can either do:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="Some text from message 1" />
    <Separator />
    <TextBlock Text="Some text from message 1" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Which gives you the separator only as big as the biggest textblock.

**OR**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text from message 1" />
    <Separator />
    <TextBlock Text="Some text from message 1" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Which makes the StackPanel stretch to its parent, and therefore makign the separator take up the whole width.

Comment: @Michael Ciechan Thank you a lot for that separator fix. Is there anything to make vertical separator too?

And maybe can you help me with that problem too:

Also I want to fix my problem with positions of elements (I have TextBlocks, TreeViews and ListViews). My workspace is Height="400" Width="625", and when I Start my GUI, and drag & resize window I mess up whole text and construction of my GUI.

Thanks, a lot!

Comment: You probably have things aligned in all sorts of directions. Could you post another question with the bare xaml and a picture of what is happening.